# How to enable sleep option in Windows 10 power menu under Ubunto host kvm?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, kvm, sleep-mode

I am running guest Windows 10 under Ubuntu host kvm. How to enable sleep option in Windows 10 power menu? I see only restart and shutdown entries in power menu.

[EDIT]Question can be rephrased, as How to Enable S3 power state on Windows 10 Guest under KVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question

1. Set **suspend-to-mem enabled** to **yes**.

   ```
   <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='yes'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='yes'/>
   </pm>
   ```
2. Install video driver for Windows 10 guest from https://people.redhat.com/vrozenfe/qxlwddm/

Comment: https://people.redhat.com/vrozenfe/qxlwddm/ this link is broken, do you have more details on the video driver or some links?

Comment: look here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU/Guest_graphics_acceleration
(I did not test it )

Answer (score 0):

Press alt + F4 at the same time. A pop up message should come up saying: 
"Shut down windows. What do you want the computer to do?"
Click on the down button beside "Shut down".
There should be an option above "Shut down" which is "Sleep".
Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Sleep option for me. Seems that kvm need to be configured to enable it...